# How do you get the component of a vector in the direction of a ray

Tags: c++, vector, game-physics

I have an object moving in the direction of vector A.
There's another vector B which points in an arbitrary direction (but can be considered an infinite line)

I want to get vector C, which is a vector in the direction of B, but with the magnitude of the A's component in the direction of B.

To illustrate, if vector A was Vector(1,.5,0) and vector B was Vector(0,1,0)
Then my vector C would be Vector(0,.5,0).

Easy enough if B is aligned on an axis, but how can I do this if B is something like (6,3,8)?

Comment: Isnt that just projecting A onto B? Also, in my opinion this is better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `dot(A, normalize(B))`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about programming.

Comment: It's specifically for a game, and has to be coded in C++ ... it's not a raw math question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that won't give me the length of the component in question, will it?

Comment: That gives you the length. You can multiply it by `normalize(B)` to get the vector.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I ran some tests.  It looks like it works!  If you post it as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `C = normalize(B)`. (divide `B` by its length)

Then `dot(A, C)` gives you the length of the desired vector, and `dot(A, C) * C` is the vector itself.

Comment: Is that pseudocode or refers to a library I'm not aware of?

Comment: `dot` refers to the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). Given two 3D vectors with coordinates (a,b,c) and (x,y,z), it's the value of `a*x + b*y + c*z`.

Comment: @MatG Pseudocode, but I think it also counts as valid GLSL.